# How to update RecyclerView adapter using DiffUtil

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, diff, android-adapter

Im used to create a new Adapter and an new RecycleView every time I needed  to update the alarms that in the RecycleView. unfortunately it just a very expensive "solution". I saw online that I can use DiffUti, but Im not sure how to implement it.
I created a DiffUtil class:

```
public class AlarmDiffCallBack extends DiffUtil.Callback{
private final ArrayList<SingleAlarm> oldList;
private final  ArrayList<SingleAlarm> newList;

public AlarmDiffCallBack( ArrayList<SingleAlarm> oldList, ArrayList<SingleAlarm> newList) {
    this.oldList = oldList;
    this.newList = newList;
}

@Override
public int getOldListSize() {
    return oldList.size();
}

@Override
public int getNewListSize() {
    return newList.size();
}

@Override
public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
    return oldList.get(oldItemPosition).getAlarmIndex() == newList.get(newItemPosition).getAlarmIndex();
}

@Override
public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
    return oldList.get(oldItemPosition).getAlarmIndex() == newList.get(newItemPosition).getAlarmIndex();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Object getChangePayload(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
    // Implement method if you're going to use ItemAnimator
    return super.getChangePayload(oldItemPosition, newItemPosition);
}
```

}

and this is one of the places I want to update the recycleView in(replace the "creatAdapter" with the DiffUtil):

```
 public void add_alarm(final Context context) {
    //creating a new alarm and set the relevant varible to the addAlarm function
    button_add_alarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //the calndar is without the right day, the day is added in the handler(int the loop)
            Calendar calendarForAlarm = timePickerToCalendar(alarmTimePicker);
            alarmsList = alarmHandler.add_alarm(context, checkBoxes, alarmMessage, alarmsList, alarm_manager, calendarForAlarm, repeatAlarm);
            alarmsList=alarmHandler.sortAlarms(alarmsList);
            creatAdapt();
        }
    });
}
```

I just cant figure out how to use this class to update my Adapter. Im pretty new to android and programming in general, hope this quotation is OK. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you need your adapter to have a method to update your data, like that:

```
public void setNewAlarms(List<SingleAlarm> newAlarms){
    // oldAlarms is the list of items currently displayed by the adapter
    AlarmDiffCallBack diffCallBack = new AlarmDiffCallBack(oldAlarms, newAlarms);

    // Second parameter is to detect "movement". If your list is always sorted the same way, you can set it to false to optimize
    DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffCallBack, true);

    // This will notify the adapter of what is new data, and will animate/update it for you ("this" being the adapter)
    diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
}
```

And then you just have to call `myAdapater.setNewAlarms(alarmsList)` from outside the adapter, with the new data.

You can also take a look at the [following repository](https://github.com/mrmike/DiffUtil-sample) that implements it

Comment: You helped me get much closer to the solution, however it still dont work for me.. First of all, I saw that in your repository you update your list manually(list.clear(); list.addall(); - should I add those list even though I operate diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)?
In addition, with those function and without, It just dosent update my RecyclerView, maybe my AlarmDiffCallBack worng?
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Your *areItemsTheSame* and *areContentsTheSame* methods are the same.

getChangePayload only gets triggered if areItemsTheSame returns true and areContentsTheSame returns false, so I think it'll never trigger